# background image not responsive on mobile

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When on mobile screen sizes, the image gets responsive to a time where the image gets cut and is no more responsive.
I will show code and image for clarification.

```
const SignIn = ({ setDisplayScreen }: Props) => (
  <ScreenDiv>
    <ImageContainer>
      <FirstImageDiv />
    </ImageContainer>
    <FormDiv>
      <SignInInput placeholder="Username" />
      <SignInInput placeholder="Password" />
      <SignUpButton
        style={{
          cursor: 'pointer',
        }}
      >
        Sign in
      </SignUpButton>
      <ForgotUserNameParagraph>
        Forgot username or password
      </ForgotUserNameParagraph>
      <SignUpParagraph
        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        onClick={() => setDisplayScreen('SignUpOptions')}
      >
        Don’t have an account? Sign up
      </SignUpParagraph>
    </FormDiv>
  </ScreenDiv>
);

export default SignIn;
```

image component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { signin, mobileSignin } from '../../assets/images';
import device from '../../config/device';

const FirstImageDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${signin});
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    background-image: url(${mobileSignin});
    width: 100%;
    height: 34.3vh;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
`;
export default FirstImageDiv;
```

[image: non respnosive]
[image: responsive]

I tried to use background size contain it becomes to small and outside the context of the div
What can I do for it to continue displaying correctly like the responsive one.
what css tricks could be use to fix the situation?